# Vue.js combine data from RESP API

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I need combine multple API calls on a final object, this because API have limits to be consumed, any have an idea how is possible combine multiple calls in same final object, next is an example of my code, I need all data in this.lista but is not working:

```
  created(){
    this.$http.get('/api/transactions?senderId=8642612272713533685S&limit=1&offset=000')
    .then( function(res){
      console.log(res.body.count);
      let limit = Math.ceil(res.body.count/1000);
      console.log(limit);
      let m = {};
      let off = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
          this.$http.get('/api/transactions?senderId=8642612272713533685S&limit=1000', {params:{offset: off}})
          .then( function(data){
             this.lista = { ...this.lista, ...data.body.transactions } 
          } )

          off = off + 1000;
       }
      }
    );
  }
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Promise.all` is most likely what you are looking for. I will write just enough code for you to understand where to go.

```
// Populate your array array with URLs you want to get
let urls = ["url1", "url2", "...and so on"];
// Make into web request promises
let httpReqPromises = urls.map( url => this.$http.get(url) )

// Wait for all of them to resolve
Promise.all(httpReqPromises).then(allResponses => {
    // Put them all together
    this.lista = allResponses.reduce((a, b) => ({...a, ...b}, {})
})
```

The only work I leave up to you is how you populate the `url` variable.